# How to make varaible visible after initialization?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that initialize a map and returns a DOM container:

```
async function initialize(config, container) {
    var map = await initializeMap(config, container);
}
```

I can create some of instancies using method above.

Thern there is another function below, that should access to `map` variable:

```
 function edit() {
      map.api.edit({ });
 }
```

How to do that in case when I have some intancies of map?

Comment: From where are you calling `edit`? Try moving that inside the `initialize` function.

Comment: you should make your own promise and `resolve(map)` after the async function and call edit as promise.then

Comment: I call edit() from click by element, how to get acess to it from click?

Comment: Could you explain more, how to resolve it using promise?

Comment: yes, I ca move edit() into initialization. but how then to call it from DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass on the `map` from a function to another, the "best" way is to return the map or use classes/objects.

It would be easy if you could to as such:

```js
async function initialize(config, container) {
    var map = await initializeMap(config, container);
    return map;
}

function edit(map) {
    map.api.edit({ });
}
```

or

```js
class MapManager {
    constructor() {
        this.map = undefined; // Not required lol
    }
    async initialize(config, container) {
        this.map = await initializeMap(config, container);
    }
    edit() {
        map.api.edit({ });
    }
}

var map_manager = new MapManager();
map_manager.initialise(my_config, div_container)
.then(() => map_manager.edit());
```

Note that it could be interesting that `edit` fails when `initialize` is not finished or awaits that `initialize` finishes (be creating a promise).

Otherwise if you can't do that, you'll have to use a global variable.

```js
var map;

async function initialize(config, container) {
    map = await initializeMap(config, container);
}

function edit() {
    map.api.edit({ });
}
```

If possible, avoid this last way because it disables you from making multiple maps. And be careful to wait that initialize finishes before calling edit otherwise you'll get unexpected results

Comment: In the first exmaple you return map from initialize, then how do you get it in edit?

 `<button onclick="initialize({})"`

Comment: Oh you're in a button event ! Then you'll have to make a variable (maybe global) made for the button. Then, you can use an auxiliary function `function button_handler() { var map = ...;  button_map = map;
}`. Maybe `<button onclick="button_map = initialize({})">` could work. And then, when a button is pressed for edit, do simply  `<button onclick="edit(button_map)">`